# Getting type error when trying to add element in a Arraylist from an int array

Tags: java, list, recursion, arraylist

I'm trying to solve leetcode sum 39.
It returns a list of all possible combination of elements in given array such that their sum equals to the target. Repetition of elements is allowed

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> combinationList(int[] up, ArrayList<Integer> p, int target, int n) {

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> outer = new ArrayList<>();
        if(target==0){
            outer.add(p);
            return outer;
        }
        if(target<0){
            return new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        }
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for(int i=n;i<up.length;i++){
            result.addAll(combinationList(up, p.add(up[i]), target-up[i],i));
        }
        return result;

    }
```

I want to add int element of i'th index of 'up' array to 'p' arraylist, thus I did p.add(up[i]) ,
but I'm getting error `java: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer>`.

Comment: Here: `combinationList(up, p.add(up[i]), target-up[i],i));` -- `p.add(up[i])` returns a boolean, but the second argument to `combinationList` is supposed to be an ArrayList.

Comment: So what can be done to make it work. I need to add element in function call itself to make my algo work else I'll need to think totally diff approach. Thankyou

Comment: I don't follow what your logic is supposed to be doing, but if you want to add `up[i]` to `p` and then pass it to `combinationList`, you can do that in two statements: first `p.add(up[i])`, and then `result.addAll(combinationList(up, p, , target-up[i],i));`. Or write a method that adds an element to a list and returns the result, and pass such a method call as the second argument to the `combinationList` call.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did what u said but was getting incorrect output, so I figured out that my code has one flaw, the changes made in list p were also made in list outer, so instead of outer.add(p), I stored copy of p in an list and added that list to outer which gave the desired output